# Query to return a row for each separated value in column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have some SQL log data like this:

| date | user | actions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | dave | changed; added:apple |
| 2023-01-02 | gail | changed; removed:apple |
| 2023-01-03 | mick | changed; added:apple; removed:banana; added:cherry; removed:durian |
| 2023-01-04 | dave | changed; removed:banana; added:cherry |

I want a query that splits the actions into separate returned rows, eg actions for user dave in January

| date | user | action | item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | dave | added | apple |
| 2023-01-04 | dave | removed | banana |
| 2023-01-04 | dave | added | cherry |

There can be a one or many actions in the source column, like 10 or more. The actual data is a bit more complex; I've simplified to key elements. Typical queries I need would be changes for a particular user or a particular fruit in a time period.

I haven't found anything quite like this problem.

Comment: What is the SQL Server version that you are using ?

Comment: Version 14 (14.0.3381)  aka SQL Server 2017

Comment: [`String_Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) and `cross apply` would be a start. Split on `;` first, then split those results on `:`. Is the resulting order of the rows important, i.e. they must match the order in `actions`? You may need a separate splitter function that returns an ordinal value for each element returned. The results would also need an additional column to preserve the order.

Comment: Row order is not an issue, I think.  The "date" column is actually a timestamp so provides the required ordering.  The same "fruit" (actually a role applied to a user) won't occur twice in the same cell.  I might need to find changes that have occurred for a user or a group of users in a time range for problem diagnosis or to reverse automated changes.

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted.  The source table format is plainly bad design, but it's a legacy app we have to work with as is.  I'd expect this technique would be useful to others.  It won't be the first or last time csv data ends up in a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As HABO said in comment, [string_split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) on `;` then split on `:` using `charindex()`, `left()` & `right()`.

You can filter for the required in `where` clause

```
select t.[date], t.[user], a.[action], a.[item]
from   yourtable t
       cross apply string_split(actions, ';') s
       cross apply
       (
           select [action] = left(s.value, charindex(':', s.value) - 1),
                  [item]   = right(s.value, len(s.value) - charindex(':', s.value))
       ) a
where  t.[user]       = 'dave'
and    trim(s.value) <> 'changed'
```

Comment: Tweaked code for actual table and added selection clauses then this works v nicely.  TIL.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution based on `STRING_SPLIT()` and `PARSENAME()` functions.

Assumption is that the *actions* column values don't contain dots.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (_date DATE PRIMARY KEY, [user] VARCHAR(30), actions VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @tbl (_date, [user], actions) VALUES
('2023-01-01', 'dave', 'changed; added:apple'),
('2023-01-02', 'gail', 'changed; removed:apple'),
('2023-01-03', 'mick', 'changed; added:apple; removed:banana; added:cherry; removed:durian'),
('2023-01-04', 'dave', 'changed; removed:banana; added:cherry');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t._date, t.[user]
    , PARSENAME(t2.tokens, 2) AS [action]
    , PARSENAME(t2.tokens, 1) AS item
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(actions, ';') AS t1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(TRIM(t1.value), ':', '.')) AS t2(tokens)
WHERE t1.value LIKE '%:%'
    AND [user] = 'dave';
```

**Output**

| _date | user | action | item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | dave | added | apple |
| 2023-01-04 | dave | removed | banana |
| 2023-01-04 | dave | added | cherry |

Comment: Aside: [`ParseName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is not a universal parser. For some examples of how well it works please see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tj2SmLDu). Playing games with `replace` to add/remove/swap periods (`.`) isn't a panacea. Ref: [Rules for Regular Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [`QuoteName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Answer (score 1):

perhaps something like this

```
WITH SplitActions AS (
  SELECT
    [date],
    [user],
    TRIM(value) AS action_item
  FROM elg_surveyBase
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(actions, ';')
),
ActionDetails AS (
  SELECT
    [date],
    [user],
    TRIM(SUBSTRING(action_item, 1, CHARINDEX(':', action_item) - 1)) AS action,
    TRIM(SUBSTRING(action_item, CHARINDEX(':', action_item) + 1, LEN(action_item))) AS item
  FROM SplitActions
)
SELECT
  [date],
  [user],
  action,
  item
FROM ActionDetails
WHERE [user] = 'dave'
  AND [date] BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-01-31';
```